# How to Skip Line from CSV File

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to make a trend with csv file and I want to skip line from first to 4th.
Can you tell me how to do this?

// my csv file :

Cho 1647 
Stretching: Casting Unit: Drive Chill Roll: Speed Actual Value

> Date;Time;Value;Unit
>
> 22.01.2019  ;05:54:08;13.05;m/min
>
> 22.01.2019  ;07:29:30;19.65;m/min
>
> 22.01.2019  ;07:29:31;15.35;m/min
>
> 22.01.2019  ;07:29:32;8.55;m/min
>
> 22.01.2019  ;07:29:32;12.55;m/min
>
> 22.01.2019  ;07:29:33;12.96;m/min

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("CSV Chart");
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();

        final LineChart<String, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        yAxis.setLabel("Actual Value");
        xAxis.setLabel("Time Value");
        lineChart.setTitle("PVSS Trend");

        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

        series.setName("Actual Value");

        try (CSVReader dataReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\190122_cr_speed.csv"),';'))
        {   
            //String line01 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\190122_cr_speed.csv")).get(0);
            //System.out.print(line01);

            String[] nextLine; int i = 0; int j =0;
            while ((nextLine = dataReader.readNext()) != null)
            {
                String year = String.valueOf(nextLine[0]);
                String time = String.valueOf(nextLine[1]);
                float pvssvalue = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[2]);
                String unit = String.valueOf(nextLine[3]);

                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(year+time, pvssvalue));   
            }
        }

        lineChart.getData().addAll(series);
        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 960, 540);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try withSkipLines() in CSV reader?

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first four lines use a counter and `continue`

```
while ((nextLine = dataReader.readNext()) != null)
{
     if (counter++ < 4)
         continue;
     ....
}
```

maybe you can use one of your unused variables `i` or `j` ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of this, but you may be a more talented Java programmer than I am, but I don't know why you're using CSVReader instead of Scanner [(Scanner API)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Scanner has a built in nextLine() function and is able to read .csv files.

Comment: Because a CSV file can contain a lot of logic that would otherwise need to be handled by the developer e.g. handing embedded commas in quotes etc.

Comment: You can just substring out the commas lol that's not even hard. (e.g. StringBuilder substring method) I couldn't even find CSVReader in vanilla Java API, so it's an outside method, which is arguably more difficult than an extra line of code.

Comment: Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values to understand the many varieties of data which can be in a csv file